# sqlsrv not showing up in phpinfo.

Tags: sql-server, php5

I'm using Win server 2k12, php 5.5.12, on wamp. 
Edited php.ini (both on apache dir and php dir) to add php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll and the php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll, and configured the extension dir path correctly. Happily, wamp is showing up those extentions at the PHP extension menu,  and after ticking it and restarting all services,  phpinfo is not showing up these changes! Not in the registered PHP streans entry,  no anywhere. 
Do you have any idea why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try copy your edited php.ini to windows/system32/ and restart your services, if it works, your path is incorrect

Comment: If you have working phpinfo, just look on path to used php.ini (Loaded Configuration File) and check that file, it will be probably somewhere in wamp dir.

Answer (score 1):

For your reference:
http://sohu.io/questions/3778559/install-sqlsrv-extension-for-php-on-wamp

If you are editing `c:\wamp\bin\php\php.ini`, do not edit that file just edit the one given by wamp server php.ini file, e.g. `c:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin\php.ini`

one more thing:
64 bit WAMP server was not able to connect using the drivers

- `extension = php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll;`
- `extension = php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll;`

Make sure your wampserver is based on 32bit